# bupaR package: How to extract edges values as a data frame?

Tags: r, tidyverse

[image]

I would need some help with extracting values from different edges into a tibble.

For example, in from the screenshot, Open to Pending User Info is 46.44 hours, Work in Progress to Closed is 1.28 hours.

Output would be:

```
From             | To                | Value
Open             | Pending User Info | 46.44
Work in Progress | Closed            | 1.28
```

Reproducible code

```
library(bupaR)
res <- patients %>%
  filter_activity_presence(c("X-Ray", "MRI SCAN"), method = "none")  %>%
  process_map()

glimpse(res)

$ jsHooks      : list()
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "grViz" "htmlwidget"
 - attr(*, "package")= chr "DiagrammeR"
 - attr(*, "base_precedence")='data.frame': 14 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ next_act       : chr [1:14] NA NA NA "ARTIFICIAL_END" ...
  ..$ act            : chr [1:14] "ARTIFICIAL_END" "ARTIFICIAL_END" "ARTIFICIAL_END" "Blood test" ...
  ..$ aid            : chr [1:14] "1237" "999" "1000" "1237" ...
  ..$ case           : chr [1:14] "496" "499" "500" "496" ...
  ..$ start_time     : POSIXct[1:14], format: "2018-05-04 03:30:59" "2018-05-04 23:53:27" "2018-05-05 07:16:02" ...
  ..$ end_time       : POSIXct[1:14], format: "2018-05-04 03:30:59" "2018-05-04 23:53:27" "2018-05-05 07:16:02" ...
  ..$ min_order      : num [1:14] Inf Inf Inf 7 5 ...
  ..$ next_start_time: POSIXct[1:14], format: NA NA NA ...
  ..$ next_end_time  : POSIXct[1:14], format: NA NA NA ...
  ..$ from_id        : int [1:14] 1 1 1 3 5 5 NA 5 2 2 ...
  ..$ to_id          : int [1:14] NA NA NA 1 1 1 2 3 4 4 ...
 - attr(*, "edges")= tibble [5 x 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ from   : chr [1:5] "ARTIFICIAL_START" "Blood test" "Registration" "Triage and Assessment" ...
  ..$ to     : chr [1:5] "Registration" "ARTIFICIAL_END" "Triage and Assessment" "ARTIFICIAL_END" ...
  ..$ from_id: int [1:5] 2 3 4 5 5
  ..$ to_id  : int [1:5] 4 1 5 1 3
  ..$ value  : num [1:5] 3 1 3 2 1
 - attr(*, "nodes")= tibble [5 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ node   : chr [1:5] "ARTIFICIAL_END" "ARTIFICIAL_START" "Blood test" "Registration" ...
  ..$ from_id: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
  ..$ value  : num [1:5] 3 3 1 3 3
  ..- attr(*, "na.action")= 'omit' Named int 6
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "6"
```

It seems the values are stored in `jshooks` list object.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can access the attributes as below

```
attr(res, 'base_precedence')
attr(res, 'edges')
```